# How to add a SQL Server database in a WCF element

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, wcf

I have a WCF service which is running perfectly. I want to add a SQL Server database to it but when I am going to Solution Explorer and right click `Add - Add new item` I don't see the SQL Server database item in the dropdownlist choice.

I created this under new project C# WCF Service Application. Any idea why the SQL Server database item is not there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.  The database is located under another Tab (DATA) and I was in the TAB (WEB).